# Enabling markers for hover doesn't appear to work

Tags: highcharts

According to the high charts docs [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.marker.enabled) you should be able to enable markers only on hover.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I wasn't able to get this to work, so went to their JSFiddle, but the jsfiddle doesn't appear to work either.  Am I missing something, or is there a bug here?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-enabled-false/

UPDATE:
Based on comments this apparently works in some contexts.  Here's the context I've tested this in, and confirmed it to not function as stated:

- OS X 10.9

  - Chrome 31.0.1650.63
  - Safari 7.0 (9537.71)
  - Firefox 26.0

Comment: That example jsFiddle works for me. Hovering over the points shows that marker appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to confusion regarding the expected behaviour.

Setting the hover enable parameter to true for markers doesn't enable markers when hovering over the series, only for hovering directly over the markers.  There does not appear to be a setting to enable markers when hovering over the series in HighChart's current API.